# How to generate inter cortexA9 interrupts based on internal timers

Tags: timer, interrupt, bare-metal, zynq, cortex-a

I've set up my artyz7 (dual core cortexA9) to receive dataframes through ethernet from my laptop and i want to create an interrupt from a9_0 to a9_1 core that starts a timer for 200ms everytime a dataframe with different time properties is sent.
a9_0 handles all the parsing of frames and i want the a9_1 to keep hard time for buffers that frames with same time properties go into.

For example:

I send a frame with seconds stamp 1.1s, the a9_0 parses it and puts it in a buffer. At that time i want to send an interrupt to a9_1 to start a 200ms timer. For that 200ms timeframe i want every frame with stamp 1.1s to go into that buffer. If a frame with 1.2s comes in, i want to send another interrupt to a9_1 to start another timer for 200ms etc.
I have implemented all the frame handling and all i need is this timer to not block a9_0s parsing.

Both a9s are on baremetal.

Is this possible?